# How to merge duplicate nodes by label

Tags: duplicates, gephi

Gephi has an option to merge duplicate nodes. It asks which column I want to use to identify duplicates.

However, the Label column does not identify any duplicates despite there being some (e.g. it doesn't recognize two nodes labeled "Jim" as duplicates).

How to merge duplicate nodes by label? I have over 100,000 nodes.